# Image Processing Android Application for an OMR Sheet

Tags: android, json

I am trying to develop an android application that can read an [OMR sheet](http://www.omrtestsheet.com/omr-sheet-sample/200-Questions-OMR-Sheet.GIF) and then convert this data into JSON.

Basically , the application takes a picture of the OMR Sheet and then "reads" it. i.e figures out the answers selected for each question and then stores it in JSON format.

I have no exposure in image processing and it would be really helpful if someone would point me in the right direction.

Comment: did you get any solution,,>